# How to pass the row and column instead of the value in a custom Google Sheets function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function calculateIntervall(note) {//The passing argument gives me the value of the cell with the note, NOT the column or row of particularly this cell
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var col = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();//get the column of note anyhow?
  var row = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow();//get the row of note anyhow?
  note = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(row, col).activate().getNote();//get the value of the note
  return col + row;
};
```

This is just an example program, that explains my question the best. The current program returns the sum of the row and the column of the active cell (the cell with the function). But I need the sum of the parameters of the cell with the note.

I just want to have the row and the column kinda like this (using the standard functions):

```
=ROW(note)
=COLUMN(note)
```

The functions usually look like this:

```
=ROW(A5) -> this returns 5
=COLUMN(C2) -> this returns 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeof() parameters to custom functions varies. For example:

```
function custom_function(p) {
    return typeof(p);
}

=custom_function(A1:A1)   // returns "number" or "string" depending upon value is in the single cell A1.
=custom_function(B1:B2)   // returns "object" - a 2 dimenstional array representing the values in the cells in the range.
=custom_function("C1:C1") // returns "string" - representing "C1:C1"
```

As the last shows, you can pass in a string, representing a range, which you can then process as you require within the function:

```
function custom_function(cell) {
    if(!cell.map && (typeof(cell === "string"))) { // not an array or a number 
       var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(cell);
       var column = range.getColumn();
       var row = range.getRow();
       return "c: "+column+" r: "+row;
    }
    else {
      return "Invalid Parameter";
    }
}
```

There is a fuller discussion about passing range values into custom functions at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-to-pass-a-range-into-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheets

Including solutions to the problem that if a range reference is passed in as a string your can't then copy the cell containing `=custom_function("C1:C1")` and have the cell references automatically updated.

**Update to address the comment**: a fairly simple way to be able to copy a custom function around with automatically updated cell references is shown below.

```
=custom_function(A1:C3; ROW(A1); COLUMN(A1); ROW(C3); COLUMN(C3))
```

So in the actual GAS script function now has 5 parameters: parameter-1 is a 2-dimensional array of the cell values, p2 and p3 are the row and column of the top left hand side of the array and p4 and p5 are the row and column of the bottom right hand side of the array.

Or if you don't actually care about the values, or are happy to re-create the range in the custom function using the co-ordinates simply:

```
=custom_function(ROW(A1); COLUMN(A1); ROW(C3); COLUMN(C3))
```

Comment: ok so i think i have to search for a diferent solution because i need the reference to automatically update itself

Comment: @RedFox - checkout the link I provided for inspiration. Unfortunately there isn't an obvious - applies anywhere - solution to the problem of passing a range to a custom function. But I've updated the answer with another solution.